# Add argument in scipy.optimize

Tags: python, scipy-optimize

I am trying to use scipy.optimize.minimize (simplex method) for minimizing the following function

```
argmin (sum(i=0 to 9) (a*i - b_i)**2)
```

I would like to obtain the value of a. I have 10 values of b_i (i have it already calculated outside the function) that i want to insert in the function

```
def f(a, b):
    func = 0
    for i in range(10):
        func+= (a*i - b[i])**2
    return func
init = [1]
out= optimize.minimize(f, init, method='nelder-mead')
```

it gives an error saying:  `f() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'`

How can i make it run.

Comment: What if you do `init = [1 , 1]`? You should pass two values to objective function. Or `def f(a)` (as you said `b` calculated already, then just remove it from arguments.)

Comment: but ``b`` is not one value, it has 10 values. I have corrected now.

Comment: Great! Put `b[i]` instead of `b`! I mean : `func+= (a*i - b[i])**2` and also remove `b` from function arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about this:

```
def f(a):
    func = 0
    for i in range(10):
        func+= (a*i - b[i])**2
    return func
init = [1]
out= optimize.minimize(f, init, method='nelder-mead')
```

as you said your target variable is `a` and you have values for `b`, then you need to construct Obj function with one argument I guess.

Comment: where do i define ``b[i]``? outside the function?

Comment: @Lalu Exactly before the function, you should define `b`! it should be something iterable like a list. for example: `b = [1,2,3]` (values maybe something else I don't know what they are.)

Comment: great thank you very much. it works!

Comment: @Lalu glad to hear.

Answer (score 0):

There is an optional parameter called `args()` in `scipy.optimize.minimize` using which you can pass arguments to the objective function as a tuple. You can do this as follows:

```python
from scipy.optimize import minimize
b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] # for example

def f(a, b):
    func = 0
    for i in range(10):
        func+= (a*i - b[i])**2
    return func

init = [1]
out = minimize(f, init, args=(b), method='nelder-mead')
print(out)
```